# read my json files from google drive with python I want to transfer to neo4j database in aura db, how do I do it?

Tags: python, neo4j, google-drive-api

read my json files from google drive with python
I want to transfer to neo4j database in aura db, how do I do it?

I have not done such a process before, I do not have any information, can you help?
I think there are a few methods, which method should I use and how do I use that method?

Comment: See [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/languages-guides/neo4j-python/) to learn how to use Python with neo4j. But you don't necessarily need to use Python to import from a JSON file. See the doc for importing using [apoc.load.json](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.load/apoc.load.json/) with Cypher.

Comment: Thank you. I have solved the problem. I connected to the Microsoft drive and added the bouquet name and key_path where my json files are in my code.